# How to use MultiPiece

Tags: haskell, yesod

I'm completely new to Yesod (and not very experienced in haskell) and I'm trying to build my first handler. I scraffolded my app using default parameters (I'm using Yesod 0.9.4.1 version and choose postgresql in scraffolding) and now I'm trying to retrieve some data from a table using selectList. I defined a new table (let's call it Foo) in models config file:

```
    Foo
        xStart Int
        yStart Int
```

and want to pass a list of FooId's and some other Foo attributes so I defined a route:

`/foos/#Int/#Int/*FooId FoosReturnR GET`

and a handler:

```
    module Handler.FoosReturn where

    import Import

    selectWindowSize :: Int 
    selectWindowSize = 10000

    getFoosReturnR :: Int -> Int -> [FooId] -> Handler RepPlain
    getFoosReturnR x y withoutIds = do
        foos <- runDB $ selectList [FooId /<-. withoutIds, 
               FooXStart <. x + selectWindowSize,
               FooXStart >=. x - selectWindowSize, 
               FooYStart <. y + selectWindowSize,
               FooYStart >=. y - selectWindowSize] [] 
        return $ RepPlain $ toContent $ show foos
```

I imported the handler in Application.hs and added it to cabal file and now when I'm trying to run it I receive an error saying that FooId is not an instance of MultiPiece - but when I try to make it an instance there is an error saying that FooId is a type synonym and cannot be  an instance of MultiPiece - how to resolve this problem?

---

EDIT:
Daniel: well, actually I don't know what exactly is FooId - it's a part of Yesod's magic which I don't fully understand so far - it's generated automatically from the table definition - but it's a some kind of a number.

Because I don't know how to use MultiPiece I switched to simpler solution and modified:

route: `/foos/#Int/#Int/#String FoosReturnR GET`

handler: [added also some logging]

```
    module Handler.FoosReturn where

    import Import
    import Data.List.Split
    import qualified Data.Text.Lazy as TL

    selectWindowSize :: Int 
    selectWindowSize = 10000

    getFoosReturnR :: Int -> Int -> String -> Handler RepPlain
    getFoosReturnR x y withoutIds = do
        app <- getYesod
        liftIO $ logLazyText (getLogger app) ("getFoosReturnR('" `TL.append` (TL.pack $ (show x) ++ "', '" ++ (show y) ++ "', '" ++ withoutIds ++ "') "))
        foos <- runDB $ selectList [FooId /<-. (map (\a -> read a :: FooId) $ splitOn "," withoutIds), 
               FooXStart <. x + selectWindowSize,
               FooXStart >=. x - selectWindowSize, 
               FooYStart <. y + selectWindowSize,
               FooYStart >=. y - selectWindowSize] [] 
        return $ RepPlain $ toContent $ show foos
```

and now it is compiling but when I browse to: http://localhost:3000/sectors/1/1/1,2 I get a page containing only:
            Internal Server Error
            Prelude.read: no parse

Well, I don't fully understand what is FooId here - how to create such a list of FooId's from list of strings containing numbers?

And of course a solution of how to make the FooId an instance of MultiPiece is most wanted.

---

EDIT:

Daniel and svachalek, thanks for your posts - I tried your (Daniel's) solution but then I was receiving errors saying that [FooId] is expected (as in the handler function declaration) but FooId type was given and this lead me to the following solution:

```
    data FooIds = FooIds [FooId] deriving (Show, Read, Eq)

    instance MultiPiece FooIds where
        toMultiPiece (FooIds fooList) = map (Data.Text.pack . show) fooList
        fromMultiPiece texts = 
            if length (filter isNothing listOfMaybeFooId) > 0
                then Nothing
                else Just $ FooIds $ map fromJust listOfMaybeFooId
            where 
                listOfMaybeFooId = map constructMaybeFooId texts
                constructMaybeFooId :: Text -> Maybe FooId
                constructMaybeFooId x = case reads (Data.Text.unpack x) :: [(FooId,String)] of
                        [(foo,_)] -> Just foo
                        _         -> Nothing
```

of course I changed the route to: `/foos/#Int/#Int/*FooIds FoosReturnR GET`

and the handler to:

```
    getFoosReturnR :: Int -> Int -> FooIds -> Handler RepPlain
    getFoosReturnR coordX coordY (FooIds withoutIds) = do
```

and now I don't get any errors during compilation nor runtime, and the only not satisfying thing is that I always receive Not Found as a result, even if I supply parameters that should give me some results - so now I have to figure out how to determine what SQL was exactly sent to the database

---

EDIT:

Now I see that the "Not Found" is connected to the problem and that the above edit is not a solution - when I browse to localhost:3000/foos/4930000/3360000 then I get the results (but then the FooIds is empty) - but when I add something like: localhost:3000/sectors/4930000/3360000/1 then I always get "Not Found" - so it's still not working..

Comment: You can write instances for type synonyms with the `TypeSynonymInstances` language extension (may also need `FlexibleInstances`). What is `FooId` a synonym for?

Comment: Daniel: I replied in an edit. Could you post some code how to make the FooId an instance of MultiPiece?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is solved:)

You could either use my implementation from one of the last edits of the question and browse to URL like: `http://localhost:3000/foos/4930000/3360000/Key {unKey = PersistInt64 3}/Key {unKey = PersistInt64 4}`
The Key type derives Read but not in a very friendly (and expected) way:)

Or change the implementation of fromMultiPiece to:

```
    instance MultiPiece FooIds where
        toMultiPiece (FooIds fooList) = map (Data.Text.pack . show) fooList
        fromMultiPiece texts = 
            if length (filter isNothing listOfMaybeFooId) > 0
                then Nothing
                else Just $ FooIds $ map fromJust listOfMaybeFooId
            where 
                listOfMaybeFooId = map constructMaybeFooId texts
                constructMaybeFooId :: Text -> Maybe FooId
                constructMaybeFooId x = case TR.decimal x of 
                        Left err -> Nothing 
                        Right (el,_) -> Just $ Key (PersistInt64 el)
```

and use URLs like: `http://localhost:3000/foos/4930000/3360000/1/2`

Many thanks to David McBride from the Yesod Web Framework Google Group

---

EDIT:  the above solution had only one disadvantage - using the PersistInt64 type - it's not a good practice to use such a details of implementation, but it can be repaired by using `fromPersistValue` and `toPersistValue` functions from `Database.Persist` as follows:

```
    instance MultiPiece FooIds where
        toMultiPiece (FooIds fooList) = map (persistValuetoText . unKey) fooList
            where
                persistValuetoText x = case fromPersistValue x of
                    Left _ -> Data.Text.pack "" 
                    Right val -> Data.Text.pack $ show (val::Int) 
        fromMultiPiece texts = 
            if length (filter isNothing listOfMaybeFooId) > 0
                then Nothing
                else Just $ FooIds $ map fromJust listOfMaybeFooId
            where 
                listOfMaybeFooId = map constructMaybeFooId texts
                constructMaybeFooId :: Text -> Maybe FooId
                constructMaybeFooId x = case TR.decimal x of 
                        Left _ -> Nothing 
                        Right (el,_) -> Just $ Key (toPersistValue (el :: Int))
```

Again, big thanks to David McBride also for this!

Answer (score 1):

Wish I could help, but yesod has something to do with web applications, as far as I know, hence I've never really looked at it. So I can just try a stab in the air, maybe I hit something.

Hayoo leads to

```
class MultiPiece s where
    fromMultiPiece :: [Text] -> Maybe s
    toMultiPiece :: s -> [Text]
```

in `Yesod.Dispatch`. Since `FooId` seems to have a `Read` instance and probably a `Show` instance, you could try

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeSynonymInstances #-}
-- maybe also FlexibleInstances

instance MultiPiece FooId where
    toMultiPiece foo = [Text.pack $ show foo]
    fromMultiPiece texts =
        case reads (unpack $ Text.concat texts) :: [(FooId,String)] of
          [(foo,_)] -> Just foo
          _         -> Nothing
```

I have no idea whether that is close to the right thing, and I would have posted it as a comment, but it's too long and there's not much formatting in comments. If it doesn't help I will delete it to not give the impression your question already has an answer when it hasn't.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also fairly new to Yesod and I gave in and added -XTypeSynonymInstances to the ghc-options in my .cabal file, and so far it's made life a lot easier for me.  I'm not sure if it's the most elegant answer to this particular problem, but otherwise I predict you'll run into that instance-of-alias error pretty frequently.  P.S. try id = (Key (PersistInt 64 n))